# Three.js JSONLoader texture issues

Tags: json, three.js, textures, blender

I'm trying to learn three.js so my next personal chalenge was to import a model from blender, everything went well but some of the textures are presenting some problems (use demo link to be able to see it).

There is a demo hosted here:https://googledrive.com/host/0BynsKHbZoT73elJpaUxqTlprVjQ/demos/3dworld/

In the js console you can examine the materials, You can also check game.models.tree

The materials exported from blender:

```
    materials" : [  {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "Material",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.699999988079071, 0.699999988079071, 0.699999988079071],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.699999988079071, 0.699999988079071, 0.699999988079071],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.125, 0.10904927551746368, 0.08209432661533356],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapLight" : "Tree_Bark_Tiled.png",
    "mapLightWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "mapNormal" : "Tree_Bark_Nor2.png",
    "mapNormalFactor" : -1.0,
    "mapNormalWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "shading" : "Phong",
    "specularCoef" : 15,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
},

{
    "DbgColor" : 15597568,
    "DbgIndex" : 1,
    "DbgName" : "Material.001",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    "colorDiffuse" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapLight" : "Tree_Leaves.png",
    "mapLightWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "mapNormal" : "Tree_Leaves_Nor.png",
    "mapNormalFactor" : -1.0,
    "mapNormalWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "shading" : "Phong",
    "specularCoef" : 15,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : true,
    "vertexColors" : false
},

{
    "DbgColor" : 60928,
    "DbgIndex" : 2,
    "DbgName" : "Material.001",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    "colorDiffuse" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapLight" : "Tree_Leaves.png",
    "mapLightWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "mapNormal" : "Tree_Leaves_Nor.png",
    "mapNormalFactor" : -1.0,
    "mapNormalWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "shading" : "Phong",
    "specularCoef" : 15,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : true,
    "vertexColors" : false
},

{
    "DbgColor" : 238,
    "DbgIndex" : 3,
    "DbgName" : "Material",
    "blending" : "NormalBlending",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.699999988079071, 0.699999988079071, 0.699999988079071],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.699999988079071, 0.699999988079071, 0.699999988079071],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.125, 0.10904927551746368, 0.08209432661533356],
    "depthTest" : true,
    "depthWrite" : true,
    "mapLight" : "Tree_Bark_Tiled.png",
    "mapLightWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "mapNormal" : "Tree_Bark_Nor2.png",
    "mapNormalFactor" : -1.0,
    "mapNormalWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "shading" : "Phong",
    "specularCoef" : 15,
    "transparency" : 1.0,
    "transparent" : false,
    "vertexColors" : false
}],
```

This is the look of the three in blender:

[image]

As you can see the transparency is gone and the texture in the bark is not mapped correctly.

Can someone please explain me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material exporting is fragile as there isn't always a clear mapping between Blender and Three.js parameters. As such, the exported materials frequently need fixing by hand.

In this case, the exporter has incorrectly guessed Tree_Bark_Tiled.png is a light map instead of a diffuse map. To fix this, change all the material references to `mapLight` and `mapLightWrap` to `mapDiffuse` and `mapDiffuseWrap`. You might also want to tweak the other properties, such as the colors and specular coefficient.

As to the transparency issue, it's a bit trickier. You probably want to add an `alphaTest` property and try different values for it, e.g. 0.5. Another thing to try is disabling `depthWrite`. Also, by default, three.js uses a special normal mapping shader if there's a normal map present. You might at first try without normal maps as that shader in my experience is poorly maintained and breaks easily. Personally I use the regular Phong material also for normal mapped things as it too has the support.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I will try it as soon as I arrive home. I'm looking forward  to see a nice looking tree :)

Comment: Tried at home and now I have a nice looking tree, thank you so much for your advice :)